# i want to display timer on my screen where test duration will be taken from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i want to display timer on my screen where test duration will be taken from database and timer to the person who is writing the online exam and should automatically logout from the test after the time duration of the exam is finished

Thanks in advance pls help me

Comment: This is not a good question. Please consider read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you know how to retrieve data from a database?

Comment: yeah i am taking and storing it in session

Comment: Please extend your question with some code as it is too broad at the moment. Are you courious about how to use System.Diagnostitcs.StopWatch?